# Can I take out my sd card?

Tags: pi-4, sd-card

I'm wanting to run different os (raspberry os, kail, etc...). What i'm wanting to know is it safe to remove the sd (turned off) and can I use other sd card in the same pi?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to remove an SD card when the Pi is off.

Yes, you can insert a different SD card with a different distribution on it.

Yes, you can swap between the SD cards when the Pi is off.

Answer (score 0):

I have more Pi than I can use and many SD Cards that I interchange.

It is perfectly safe, provided you power down first.

There are a few issues.

1. Each Pi should have a unique hostname and IP address.
2. Obviously the OS needs to match the hardware - some OS won't run on older Pi.